# como puedo pasar el valo de mi litbox en ajax==

Tags: ajax, asp.net

```
function insertar() {


    var data = {
        objpersona: {

            licencia: $("#Licencia").val(),
            categoriaid: $("#categoria").val(),
            p_ci: $("#carnet").$(this).val()
        }
    }

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "Conductor.aspx/Registrapersona",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {

            $('#myModal').modal('hide'),
                $('#tablapersona').show()
          ///  fillLimpiar();
            $('#tx').val("");
            location.reload();



            console.log("hola")

        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            alert(msg);
        }


    }).done(function (info) {
        console.log(info);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo cual es realmente tu duda pero unos consejos, si quieres usar promises, dentro del objeto ajax no necesitas pasar las funciones success y error ya que done y fail son equivalentes

```
const request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Conductor.aspx/Registrapersona",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
request.done(function (result) {
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   $('#tablapersona').show();
   $('#tx').val("");
   location.reload();
});
request.fail(function (msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  alert(msg);    
});
```

tambien existe always, te agradecería que explicases un poco más cual es tu duda y pusieses más código html.

Un slaudo